# Event ID 10020 on my DHCP Server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, ip, dhcp

Every time I restart my server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise) the following DCHP events appear with the ID 10020 in my event log. I have a static IPv6 address but this event is still being generated.

I searched on the web and on most of the forums are saying if the IPv6 address is static and is configured, to ignore this warning, but I am not so convinced

```
Event ID:      10020
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DHCP-Server
Type:          Warning
Description:
This computer has at least one dynamically assigned IPv6 address. For reliable DHCPv6 server operation you should use only static IPv6 addresses.
```

Comment: The full event text would be very helpful, rather than us having to Google for it.

Comment: I am 99% sure I have pasted the correct event text. Please verify this and correct if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Event ID 10020 = `This computer has at least one dynamically assigned IPv6 address`

Having a static IP assigned in IPv6 does not perclude a dynamic IP address assignment. IPv6 is not simply IPv4 with bigger addresses. Check your local and network configruation again.

Comment: I do not now how to configure exactly. I just added static ipv6 and i thought that will solve the problem. But i see it shows more ipv6 addresses. So i don't know what to do

Comment: The other IP must be coming from somewhere, DHCPv6 or Stateless. Sounds like this is a DHCPv6 server, is there another computer that is the DG and has announcements configured?

Comment: There is no other computer that is DG. But is no other way to check the configuration? To see maybe is something wrong, or?

Comment: If you cant find it in the configuration you'll have to break out something like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) and see what's going on at the wire.